# My application has stopped consuming from kafka's queue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am developing an application based on Spring Boot and kafka queues, but when developing the main of the application, it has stopped consuming from the queue and I do not know why.

--Main Application---

```
@Service
public class ApplicationMainClass implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    PlayerDaoRepository playerDaoRepository;
    @Autowired
    DataColectorServiceImp dataColectorServiceImp;
    @Autowired
    BattleDaoRepository battleDaoRepository;
    @Autowired
    BattleService battleService;
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ApplicationMainClass.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {

        List<Playerdao> listPlayersActive;
        List<BattleDao> battle;
        List<BattleDao> battleDaoAux;
        while (true) {
            log.info("Comienza la ejecución");
            listPlayersActive = playerDaoRepository.findByActive(true);
            for (Playerdao player : listPlayersActive) {
                try {
                    String battleString = dataColectorServiceImp.apiConexion(player.getUri());
                    if (battleString.equals("")) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    battle = player.getBatallasPlayed();
                    battleDaoAux = battleService.getBattle(battleString);
                    player.setLastGamePlayed(!battle.isEmpty() ? battle.get(battle.size()-1).getBattletlime() : LocalDateTime.MIN.toString());
                    battleDaoAux = player.kafkaHandler(battleDaoAux);
                    battleService.postBattle(battleDaoAux, player.getTag());
                    player.setBatallasPlayed(player.listBuilder(player.getBatallasPlayed(), battleDaoAux));
                    battleDaoRepository.saveAll(battle);
                    playerDaoRepository.save(player);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("", e);
                }
            }
            try {
                log.info("Termina la ejecucion");
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

StreamListener

```
  @StreamListener
    public KStream<IdBattle, textBattle>newBattle(@Input(BinderProcessor.battles)KStream<IdBattle,textBattle>battleKStream){
        updateDatabase(battleKStream);
        return null;
    }

    private void updateDatabase(KStream<IdBattle, textBattle> battleKStream) {
        battleKStream.foreach((IdBattle,textBattle)->{
            if(textBattle==null){
                playerDaoRepository.deleteById(IdBattle.getIdBattle());
            }else{
                Battle battle= playerDaoService.textTreatment(textBattle.getText(),Battle);
                battle=battleDaoService.setBattleTime(textBattle.getText(),battle);
                Event event =  playerDaoService.textTreatmentEvent(textBattle.getText(),Event);
                battle.setMap(event.getMap());
                battleDaoService.updateDatabase(battle,IdBattle.getIdBattle());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix it so that both threads of the application run at the same time, and in fact I don't even know why it has stopped consuming from the queue.

Thank you very much

Comment: You're calling `while(true)` and `Thread.sleep` in the main class and wondering why other code doesn't run? You should be able to set cron expressions in Spring with background threads, by the way (`@Scheduled` annotation)... How are we going to know if there's anything in your topics to actually read, though?

Comment: Hi @OneCriketeer, Thanks for the comment, I will look on the internet about the tag that you tell me, as for the topics, yes there are things in them, but when I created the main, they stopped receiving messages from the topics although they were in them, I have done a debug and it is like the listener code is skipped, specifically jumps from the forEach of the kstream to the end of the code without doing the methods.

Comment: KStream processing is asynchronous, so you'd need to explicitly set a breakpoint within the foreach body. Otherwise, yes, it'll create a Topology object and "skip/return it at the end" of the spring function. It probably doesn't run because you `return null` rather than the KStream object that the method signature expects and will wire into the Spring Kafka lifecycle... Btw, it's highly recommended not to use Kafka Streams with external database actions (DAO/Repository classes)

Comment: Okei, Thank you very much, I have already managed to solve it with the annotation that you told me, as for what you say about the Dao, I did not know that it was a bad practice, I will take it into account when refactoring the code. Thanks for the comment and for the advice.

Comment: Feel free to show your solution below as an answer to your own question

Answer (score 1):

Good, as we discussed in the comments the bug was based on that we can not make a thread that calls a sleep and a while true, because all the time will be using that thread and will not pass to the next, I have solved it by simply adding the tag "@Scheduled" to the main of the application.

This way we make sure that after the execution of the main we wait "x" seconds for the next execution, leaving resources for the streamListener.

Thank you very much and feel free to correct me if I have made a mistake in the explanation.